# Web service XML <Data> <Record> tag

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt

I have a PHP script that executes a web service call which returns an XML file. This part of the process works as intended. The subsequent steps in the script call an XSLT file and attempt to transform the XML to HTML.

The XSLT file seems to get loaded OK, but it fails to match the tags in the XML file and so the values in the XML file are not displayed. The hierarchy in the XML file is pretty simple.

Here is a sample of the XML file stored in a PHP variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2017-03-08">
    <Record userId="1600263" username="ppurfiel" termId="1484" dmd:surveyId="13740910">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="COLLEGE" entryKey="Academic Affairs" text="Academic Affairs"/>
        <PCI id="87603417088" dmd:lastModified="2017-02-13T16:30:56">
            <PREFIX>Mr.</PREFIX>
            <FNAME>Patrick</FNAME>
            <PFNAME/>
            <MNAME>John</MNAME>
            .
            .
            .
        </PCI>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

Here is the XSLT file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <html>
            <body bgcolor="lightgreen">
                <h1>Digital Measures PCI Screen Info:</h1>
                <B>Prefix: </B>
                <xsl:value-of select="/Data/Record/PCI/PREFIX"/>
                <br />

                <B>First Name: </B>
                <xsl:value-of select="/Data/Record/PCI/FNAME"/>
                <br />
                <B>Preferred First Name: </B>
                <xsl:value-of select="/Data/Record/PCI/FNAME"/>
                <br />
                <B>Middle Name: </B>
                <xsl:value-of select="/Data/Record/PCI/MNAME"/>
                <br />
                .
                .
                .
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I'm seeing shows the Header

> Digital Measures PCI Screen Info:

as well as the data item Labels such as "Prefix:" and "First Name:", but does not show the actual values.

I've tried locating help by searching on "web-services, xml, xslt,   tag", but have not located any helpful results.

My XML contains the tags `<Data>` and `<Record>`. This is the first web-service that I've tried that returns these tags in the XML. Could these tags be posing a problem?

I've tried both the following in my XSLT file, but without any difference:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:template match="/">
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you think this is a PHP problem, post your PHP code. Otherwise, remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems occurred due to a namespace problem.
In your XML file you set your default namespace to `xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data"`,
but in your XSLT you don't set it at all - so it would be `xmlns=""` and the matching rules of the template(s) will simply not match.

The solution is adding the namespace(s) to your XSLT `<xsl:stylesheet>` root element so that they are available for your `<xsl:template...>` rules (I somewhat improved the template rules, by the way):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dta="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data"
    xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata"
    exclude-result-prefixes="dta dmd">
    <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">         <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data">             <!-- matches /Data root element -->
    <html>
      <body bgcolor="lightgreen">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </body>
    </html>  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record/PCI">      <!-- matches sub-elements -->
    <h1>Digital Measures PCI Screen Info:</h1>
    <B>Prefix: </B><xsl:value-of select="PREFIX"/><br />
    <B>Prefix: </B><xsl:value-of select="PREFIX"/><br />
    <B>First Name: </B><xsl:value-of select="FNAME"/><br />
    <B>Preferred First Name: </B><xsl:value-of select="FNAME"/><br />
    <B>Middle Name: </B><xsl:value-of select="MNAME"/><br />
  </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of this XSLT is:

```
<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2017-03-08">
    <Record userId="1600263" username="ppurfiel" termId="1484" dmd:surveyId="13740910">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="COLLEGE" entryKey="Academic Affairs" text="Academic Affairs"></dmd:IndexEntry>
        <PCI id="87603417088" dmd:lastModified="2017-02-13T16:30:56">
            <PREFIX>Mr.</PREFIX>
            <FNAME>Patrick</FNAME>
            <PFNAME></PFNAME>
            <MNAME>John</MNAME>
            .
            .
            .
        </PCI>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

The above XSL-template is supposed to work in your PHP environment.

Comment: @PJ_Purf: I don't want to appear impolite, but accepting my answer would emphasize your appreciation :-)

Comment: My apologies.  I had too many things opened at once yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the solution to my problem/question.  Thanks to all those who responded.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:dta="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data"
  xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata"
  exclude-result-prefixes="dta dmd">
<xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dta:Data">
    <html>
      <body bgcolor="lightgreen">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="dta:Record/dta:PCI" />
        <h1>Presentations:</h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="dta:Record/dta:PRESENT[position()&lt;=5]" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dta:PCI">
    <h1>Digital Measures PCI Screen Info:</h1>
    <B>Employee Name: </B><xsl:value-of select="dta:PREFIX"/> <xsl:text> </xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="dta:FNAME"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>    <xsl:value-of select="dta:LNAME"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>     <xsl:value-of select="dta:SUFFIX"/> <br />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dta:PRESENT">
    <B>Presentation Name: </B> <xsl:value-of select="dta:NAME"/><br />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```